# Baikal Server 0.4.5 Sync-Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php5, caldav

I have some troubles using Baikal Server 0.4.5 getting always some errors, when I want to set up the sync in an app.

Environment:

- CentOS 7
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 5.5
- SELinux Enforcing (but same on permissive)

Output in httpd-error-log:

```
[Tue Aug 02 10:12:41.331903 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 20662] [client IPv4-Addr:2712] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/baikal/html/dav.php
```

Tried it with davdroid and caldav-sync.

V-Host-Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName baikal.xx.de
    ServerAlias baikal.xx.de

    Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/http/baikal.xx/synccert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/http/baikal.xx/synckey.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /.well-known/carddav /dav.php [R,L]
    RewriteRule /.well-known/caldav /dav.php [R,L]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/baikal.xx/html

    <Directory "var/www/baikal.xx.de">
            Options None
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

            SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/baikal.xx.de
            SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/baikal.xx.de

            Satisfy Any
    </Directory>

    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNull:!MD5
</VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone an idea, what to do?

Strange thing is, that I can access the url https://baikal.xx.de/dav.php/calendars/user/ via my browser on providing the credentials...

Answer (score 0):

The possible causes of "client denied by server configuration" are listed here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

If none of these appear to be to reason, then the next most likely things are:

- You are not hitting the virtual host you think you are, in which case I suggest you add individual access/error logs to your vhosts to verify that the request is landing on the vhost you thin it is.
- You have configuration that conflicts with the directives in your virtual host in the global (server) context or in an htaccess file somewhere (if enabled)